# resx strings in application pages

Tags: application-pages, localization, resource-files

I want to use strings from my resx-files in my application pages. How can I refer to my resource file?

`<h2><%$Resources:MyProject,Test_String_Heading%></h2>` results in page crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can reference it statically like that. Try this instead:

```
<h2><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text="<%$Resources:MyProject,Test_String_Heading%>"></asp:Literal></h2>
```

EDIT: it's $Resources versus &Resources.  Thanks for picking that up Bojan!

UPDATE: As noted below the $Resources method of referencing a resource is for global resources. The following should work for resources associated with your solution (...no manual copy of resource files required).

```
<h2><%=SharePointTest.MyResources.String1%></h2>
```

All you have to do to make this work is ensure that your resx has its **Access Modifier** set to **Public** and use the fully qualified resource name (i.e. namespace.class.resourceid).

Comment: Correct syntax is to use "$" instead of "&". Hence: <h2><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" Text="<%$Resources:MyProject,Test_String_Heading%>"></asp:Literal></h2>

Comment: When I do so, I get an error: `Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.MyProject.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.`

Comment: [Here](http://support.sharepointsolutions.com/entries/131561-error-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture) is a tip how to solve it manually (by copiing resx file to iis virtual dir). But isn't there a way to do it automatically while deploying?

Comment: Without seeing the code/project it's hard to say exactly what the problem is. Common issues are namespace mismatches and/or the resoruce file is set to "no code generation".

Comment: You have to copy it to <iis virtual directory>\App_GlobalResources manually or with a timer job.
[Infowise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/Comments.aspx?ArticleId=6) and [jonleon.blogspot.com](http://jonlejon.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-vs-2010-and-deploying.html) provide a solution for that. But you can't replace the mapped resources folder with it.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, there's a deployment type for the AppGlobalResources folder when you select a file in a Module SPI.